# How do I call a helper function from a CakePHP component?

Tags: cakephp

How do I call a helper function from a CakePHP component?

Comment: In general you should avoid using helpers in components, because helpers are meant to be used from views/other helpers.

Answer (score 7):

```
App::import('helper', 'Upload');
$test = new UploadHelper();
pr($test->hi());
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$this->controller->helpers[] = "helper name";
```

inside component class