# How to use a helper function in a controller?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I wrote some function in app_helper file. now i need to call that function in my controller
how i can do this in CAKEPHP

Comment: Like deceze already said, you shouldn't use a helper in your controller. But if you really want to, see this questions answer on how to do it with `App::import`: [How can we call a helper function from a cakephp component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944531/how-can-we-call-a-helper-function-from-a-cakephp-component)

Comment: Similar question: *[How to access a helper from the controller in CakePHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497975/how-to-access-a-helper-from-the-controller-in-cakephp)*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't.*

If your functions are so universal as to be used outside of views, create them in `bootstrap.php` or make a custom library/class in the `libs/` directory.

---

* <sub>You can load anything anywhere using `App::import('Helper', 'NameOfHelper')` or `ClassRegistry::init`, but you really shouldn't. The point of MVC separation is to keep your app well organized.</sub>

Comment: see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/26/helper-component-lib/ for other ways to use your code in controllers.

Comment: @deceze:  i put this function in app_controller ... is it betterway?

Answer (score 16):

```
App::uses('HtmlHelper', 'View/Helper');
$yourTmpHtmlHelper = new HtmlHelper(new View());
```

Is finally the version which works with Cakephp 2.3

Comment: And why would do you do that? :) Most of the time we should be able to use Lib classes here instead of helpers.

Comment: I would use a helper in a Controller Component for generalization and using in many controllers....

Comment: Hey, whatever it is, it worked for me in this tiny function I hardly even care about. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the helper in Controller as bellow

```
App::uses('YourHelper', 'View/Helper');

class yourController extends AppController {

public function index(){
    $yourHelper = new YourHelper(new View());
    $yourHelper->yourMethod();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was util

Answer (score 5):

```
App::import('Helper', 'Forum.Common');
    $commonHelper = new CommonHelper(new View())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use some common functions in all of your controllers like the helper does for views, 
you must use Components 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html

rather using App::import('Helper', 'NameOfHelper'), this keeps the MVC standard correct and your app well organized.

Answer (score 2):

you can  call helper function this way. suppose you helper is **DemoHelp**
and call to helper function **call_function()** then you can use this.

```
App::import('Helper', 'DemoHelp');
$DemoHelp = new DemoHelpHelper();

$DemoHelp->call_function()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Component](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html), they are stored in `Controller/Component/`

For example if you have `Controller/Component/SomeComponent.php`
and want call it on the fly in single action inside controller:

```
$this->SomeComponent = $this->Components->load('SomeComponent');
$this->SomeComponent->someFunction();
```